# Python machine learning accuracy scoring with opinions

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

So currently I am trying out many different machine learning models (KNN, Kmeans, Neural Net, Decision Trees etc. In order to find out which model is best for my situation. The part that I'm getting stuck on is that I'm basing my algorithm on opinions. Below is a single entry on X features:

```
X-array([  96255.,  114452.,  177551.,  141049.,  170292.,    8155.,
               502.,     683.])
```

Below is a sample-set of expect Y scores for the inputted features as shown above:

```
Y-array([ 70.,  60.,  70.,  70.,  70.,  65.,  50.,  40.,  60.,  80.,  70.,
        50.,  90.,  70.,  70.,  70.,  60.,  30.,  50.,  80.,  70.,  75.,
        80.,  70.,  80.,  70.,  80.,  60.,  70.,  70.,  60.,  70.,  60.,
        60.,  70.,  60.,  65.,  70.,  70.,  50.,  60.,  40.,  60.,  80.,
        75.,  70.])
```

Now the tricky part, the expect Y values are of the same input features. For example the described X-array could have the following scores matched to it: 70,60,50,70,65. Since these are opinions of people there is no right or wrong just yet, which is what I want the model to find out. However when trying to predict accuracy of all models (to see which is the best model). I get low results (obviously) since it can never match a single value to multiple expect values. Is there a good method to work with opinions and predicting opinions? Tips and advices are welcome.

Just for clearance, normally I transform the data with:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
x = scaler.fit_transform(x)
```

I test the accuracy currently with:

```
clf_NeuralNetwork.score(X_test, y_test)
```

And I use a K-Fold algorithm in order to split test and train data in order to not overfit the data. Thanks in advance!

Small update: I'm currently tempted to go with a model such as:

```
i = 0
j = 0
score = 0
for prediction in neigh1.predict(X_test):
    print(prediction)
    for predictedScore in neigh1.classes_:
        if predictedScore == y_train[i]:
            print(predictionMatrix[i][j])
            score = score + (predictionMatrix[i][j] * 100)
            print(score)
        j = j + 1;
    j=0
    i = i + 1

print(score/i)
```

Which takes the probability of an correct answer and calculates the accuracy of how far the model is off (making a 50/50 split still 50% accurate for that case).

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on a problem you are trying to solve and your data. Try to dig deeper into data points, plot some histograms and correlation plots.

Overall trees are good for data that can be split into some number of discrete blocks where regression models (and NN) are better for finding continuous relations. 

You don't have to scale feature for use in decision trees, but I recommend using normal scaler with truncation for regression models. 
Basically, I highly recommend start with XGBoost as a baseline and then try to beat it with simpler interpreting models.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into XGBoost. I did update my topic with an idea of what I am currently attempting of using. Basically I am trying to predict scores 1-10 based on a lot of features (the current set is just the beginning). So I believe trees work well, I just want to keep other options open as well.